# How to convert string into regex with the words more than 3 character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a ABRV from string. I can achieve some result , but not the final expected one.
For example, if I have `INTERNATIONAL Monetary Fund ltd` string, I need to get `IMF` from it.

I have tried this one, but it only returns `IMFl`. I need to restrict it to count only words with more than 3 characters.

```
'INTERNATIONAL Monetary Fund ltd'.match(/\b\w\B/g).join('');
```

This one doesn't work as expected

```
'INTERNATIONAL Monetary Fund ltd'.match(/\b\w{4,}\B/g).join('');
```

Comment: Should it be for all words, or a sequence of words longer than 3 characters? Like `INTERNATIONAL Monetary Fund ltd Abcd` should be `IMFA` or still `IMF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only capture the first letters of words of 4 or more characters, you can use a lookahead for 3 or more word characters after matching the first character:

```js
const abrv = 'INTERNATIONAL Monetary Fund ltd'.match(/\b\w(?=\w{3,})/g).join('');

console.log(abrv);
```